# Error in py2app

Tags: py2app

I am testing py2app on a simple test.py application, doing nothing special.

```
python == 3.6
py2app == 0.14
```

It builds fine with no errors when I give this command:

```
python3.6 setup.py py2app -A
```

but when I launch it, this is the result:

```
./dist/test.app/Contents/MacOS/test 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fabio/projvenv/dist/test.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 132, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Users/fabio/projvenv/dist/test.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 126, in _run
    exec(compile(source, script, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/fabio/projvenv/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tkinter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ValueError: character U+6573552f is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]
2017-06-24 11:32:26.266 test[65341:8804502] test Error
```

Comment: I ended up downgrading py2app to 0.12 and that fixed the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

downgrading to 0.12 fixed the issue for me. More of a workaround that a fix though but good enough for me at this point