# how to fix py2app, when py2app app is not working?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, macos-sierra, py2app

I have a simple app, named test.py:

```
import tkinter
a=tkinter.Tk()
tkinter.Label(a,text='hello!').pack()
a.mainloop()
```

and I made a folder, named test. I active virtualenv, making setup.py and then 'python3 setup.py py2app'. finally, it shows 'Done!'(that means py2app worked fine without any problem.) but when I double click on my test.app in dist directory, it fails.(test error). do you know why this problem happens and how can I fix it?
this is the error message when I run distilled/test.app/Contents/MacOS/test:

```
Contents/MacOS/test ; exit;
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File > "/Users/dariushmazlumi/Desktop/test/dist/test.app/Contents/Resources/__boo> t__.py", line 98, in <module>
   _run()
 File > "/Users/dariushmazlumi/Desktop/test/dist/test.app/Contents/Resources/__boo> t__.py", line 82, in _run
   exec(compile(source, path, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
 File > "/Users/dariushmazlumi/Desktop/test/dist/test.app/Contents/Resources/test.> py", line 1, in <module>
  import tkinter
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in > _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in_load_backward_compatible
 File "tkinter/__init__.pyc", line 36, in <module>
ValueError: character U+6573552f is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]
2017-09-06 14:08:17.090 test[1999:115511] test Error
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...99 completed.
[Process completed]
```

I'm using macOS sierra 10.12.

Comment: do you think its a bug in py2app? if yes, how to report it?

Comment: I installed a virtual macOS sierra and tried py2app there. same error message!

Answer (score 1):

wow! I searched here about py2app error, and someone had same issue! [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734959/error-in-py2app). downgrading to py2app 0.12 fixed my error.(may py2app was 0.14). thanks everyone how tried to help me.