# Is there an equivalent to the "os.listdir()" method using PyObjC?

Tags: pyinstaller, pyobjc

Is there an equivalent to the "os.listdir()" method using the PyObjC library? I want to list all of the files in a directory.

I am making my python script into an executable using PyInstaller. There is a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63611190/python-macos-builds-run-from-terminal-but-crash-on-finder-launch) where some of the "os" functionality cannot be used when launching the app in MacOS.

I found [this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1414584-contentsofdirectoryatpath) in the Foundation framework which seems like it would work, but I have not been able to convert it into the right PyObjC syntax (see error below).

```
NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath_('/Users/eturner/Desktop', true)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath_('/Users/eturner/Desktop', true)
AttributeError: 'NSFileManager' object has no attribute 'contentsOfDirectoryAtPath_'
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the objetive-c  selector for this method is `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:`. This means that the Python method is named `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath_error_` and should be used as such:

```
contents, error = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath_('/Users/eturner/Desktop', None)
```

The "error" argument for the Objective-C selector is a pass-by-reference output argument, that's why `None` is passed for the value and the return value of the Python call contains 2 values: the actual return value and the value of the pass-by-reference output argument.